# Dynamic flask URL variable is not being passed to the view function

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to pass a dynamic variable from a route in Flask into my view function. It seem's like a standard feature. But the code is displaying some odd behavior.

Here's the function:

```py
@bp.route('/<id>/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def update(id):
    return id
```

Here's the output on the http://localhost:5000/1/update page:

```
id
```

As you can see I expected the value of "1" to print, but instead the name of the parameter was printed... I have no idea why this is happening and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

(Edit: This is code from the tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a bug in the @login_required decorator from a different module. If anyone has this same error, here is what my code was...

```
def login_required(view):
@functools.wraps(view)
def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
    if g.user is None:
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return view(*kwargs)
return wrapped_view
```

"kwargs" was missing a star, so python treated it as "args" instead of "kwargs"...